# Gitlab CI only on "Release" branch?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Im pretty sure this is possibly using the "Only" tag. But I have some automated integration tests i'd like to run against only the release branch when things are pushed to it.

However the release branch is usually deleted after production deploy. So how would I go about making my gitlab CI to account for this?

or would it be something as simple as: ( I ask because for instance release branch will only exist pre-production, and also I didn't know if I needed to state the "script" as a separate job for this to work as I want it to work.

```
before_script:
  - rbenv install --skip-existing `cat .ruby-version`
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed
rspec:
  script:
    - bundle exec rspec --tag js
  only:
    - release
  tags:
    - ruby
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't matter that the release branch is deleted after deployment as long as the deployment isn't occurring in a stage before this test is run. I'm pretty sure your example YML file would work fine.